# What's a good way to mock a remote HTTPS API for unit testing my QML app?

Tags: application-development, qml, testing

I'm tinkering with a QML app that interacts with a remote REST API over HTTPS.  The "client" part of the app is neatly packaged into a component and I'd like to unit test that, but I don't want to have to rely on the remote service being available whenever I run tests, nor do I want to commit actual transactions.  Instead, I want to mock the remote service.

What is a good way to do this?  I'm developing on Ubuntu Trusty, using Ubuntu SDK 1.119.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the logic for talking to the remote API and parsing the results, is in C++ as a component plug-in, you can use the [googlemock](https://code.google.com/p/googlemock) library, packaged as `google-mock` in Ubuntu, to create unit tests that mock expected results and data. However, if the API on the server changes, your code may still fail, even though the tests would pass, as you are only testing some known expected results.

Another option is to introduce an environment variable in y our code, so that you may point the base URL to a different location, such as *localhost:12345*, and implement a mock HTTP server in Python or another language, which gets run on a random high port, which you can point the tests at. This makes running the tests a little more complicated, as you need to get the random port from the server script, and pass it on to the tests in some way. You can run this test on plain HTTP, or create a CA cert and server cert, which are included in the test suite, and add some way to ensure the networking library can load the CA into the certificate chain to validate the local HTTPS connection. However, this is all very complicated and doesn't give you any more useful results than simpler unit tests with fake data.

Beyond that, you can only talk to an actual server, with an actual valid certificate. Ideally, the remote service will providing a staging/test server for doing such testing against, and you can introduce an environment variable or similar in your code, to point it at the staging/test server, instead of the live server.